# How many playthroughs are required to complete all quests?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

On my first playthrough I killed Caesar, destroyed Brotherhood of Steel and deceived Yes Man. How many runs are required to play all quests in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4, as the final quest is different for each faction.

Another question is do you simply mean 'see' each quest or 'complete' each quest. Because, for example, it's impossible to complete both Cass' personal quest and Birds of a Feather in the same playthrough.

Comment: Edited. I tried to avoid using the word "complete", because a quest could have had countless variations with only minor changes. Apparently that's not the case.

Comment: How many playthroughs if the final quest is excluded?

Comment: @user598527 3, as NCR and Legion will fail if you get to far with House or Yes-Man (and the point they fail at means there are still quests left for House and Yes-Man after that point), but you can do all the House quests up until the final battle before killing him for Yes-Man.

Comment: This is correct for completing each of the final quests. It's at least *possible* that there are mutually exclusive quests, such as the example with Cass, that can only be accessed by going past the point of no return with a single faction, in which case you would need more than one playthrough with that faction to do all the quests.

Comment: @DCShannon There aren't. The only quests past the point of no return for each faction may have different outcomes, but none result in mutually exclusive quests. One playthrough for each faction (except for House and Yes-Man which can keep playing with each other until the final battle quest) is enough.